# Инкапсуляция Angular

Tags: angular, angular2, angular4, angular5

Изучаю Angular. Почти мгновенно, в ходе чтения мануала возникли вопросы:

Зачем нужна инкапсуляция CSS стилей в Angular и стоит ли её отключать?

Также какие плюсы/минусы есть при отключении инкапсуляции CSS?

Влияет ли инкапсуляция на производительность (нагружает ли девайс пользователя)? Если да, то сильно ли?

Как подключить "глобальный" файл стилей ко всей странице (например, reset.css), если включена инкапсуляция CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужна чтобы, очевидно, инкапсулировать стили на уровне приложения/компонента.

А какие плюсы/минусы в написании специфичных селекторов в css? Вы не хотите, чтобы стили из других компонентов с такими же классами влияли на целевой компонент.

Инкапсуляция имеет очень незначительное отношение к производительности, настолько незначительное, что можно игнорировать.

В конфигурации ангуляр приложения (файл `angular.json`) есть поле `styles`. Это массив путей к файлам стилей, которые будут применены глобально.